# Create failed for database 'ToDoList'. (Microsoft.sqlserver.smo)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I am trying to create a database using SQL server Management Studio 2012. But on clicking the create database,i am getting an error:

> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'ToDoList.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: Are you going to create a database named **ToDoList**? If yes, have you checked your path for **ToDoList.mdf**?

Comment: Moreover, I have remove tag c#, asp.net and ado.net, as they are not relevant to the question. Please [edit] the question and add them back they related to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs if the user that is trying to create the database  doesn't have the necessary permissions in SQL Server. Maybe you have read_only on.

Try using a Administrator's account to create the database or set new permission on the user that you're already using.

Heres how to grant permission to the user that you're logged in to.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717(v=sql.105).aspx